# Inheriting product category in description field - OpenErp

Tags: python, module, field, odoo, inheritance

I have this code for a product in my module:

```
_name = "purchase.requisition.line"
_description="Purchase Requisition Line"
_rec_name = 'product_id'

_columns = {
    'descripcion' : fields.char('Descripcion', size=42),
    'nrodeparte' : fields.integer('Nro. de Parte'),
    'espcifictec' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=42),
    'maquina' : fields.char('Maquina', size=42),
    'anexo' : fields.float('Anexo NRo.'),
    'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product' ),
    'product_uom_id': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Product Unit of Measure'),
    'product_qty': fields.float('Quantity', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure')),
    'requisition_id' : fields.many2one('purchase.requisition','Purchase Requisition', ondelete='cascade'),
    'company_id': fields.related('requisition_id','company_id',type='many2one',relation='res.company',string='Company', store=True, readonly=True),
}
```

In `descripcion` I got a `char` field for a description of the product I've inherited from `product.product`. Right now it's an independent field, how can I inherit the category of the product I chose in `product_id`?

I know the object is `categ_id` in the product module, and I tried this

```
'descripcion': fields.many2one('product.category','Desripcion')
```

But it doesn't works, how can I achieve this? I need to load automatically the product description (`categ_id`) in this field.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace it with a `function` field that gets the value from product_id.category_id or setup an `on_change` on the `produtct_id` that populates your category. Read the [manual](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields) and `grep` the addons folder for a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

'descripcion':fields.many2one('product.category', 'Descripcion', required=True, ondelete='cascade'),